# Regex for validating account names for NEAR protocol

Tags: regex, nearprotocol, near

I want to have accurate form field validation for NEAR protocol account addresses.

I see at https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#account-id-rules that the minimum length is 2, maximum length is 64, and the string must either be a 64-character hex representation of a public key (in the case of an implicit account) or must consist of "Account ID parts" separated by `.` and ending in `.near`, where an "Account ID part" consists of lowercase alphanumeric symbols separated by either `_` or `-`.

Here are some examples.

The final 4 cases here should be marked as invalid (and there might be more cases that I don't know about):

- `example.near`
- `sub.ex.near`
- `something.near`
- `98793cd91a3f870fb126f66285808c7e094afcfc4eda8a970f6648cdf0dbd6de`
- `wrong.near.suffix` (INVALID)
- `shouldnotendwithperiod.near.` (INVALID)
- `space should fail.near` (INVALID)
- `touchingDotsShouldfail..near` (INVALID)

I'm wondering if there is a well-tested regex that I should be using in my validation.

Thanks.

P.S. Originally my question pointed to what I was starting with at https://regex101.com/r/jZHtDA/1 but starting from scratch like that feels unwise given that there must already be official validation rules somewhere that I could copy.

I have looked at code that I would have expected to use some kind of validation, such as these links, but I haven't found it yet:

- https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/40512df4d14366e1b8e05152fbf5a898812ebd2b/packages/frontend/src/utils/account.js#L8
- https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/40512df4d14366e1b8e05152fbf5a898812ebd2b/packages/frontend/src/components/accounts/AccountFormAccountId.js#L95
- https://github.com/near/near-cli/blob/cdc571b1625a26bcc39b3d8db68a2f82b91f06ea/commands/create-account.js#L75

Comment: It is not clear what matches should be invalid and why

Comment: there's a regex in the platform spec that might help `^(([a-z\d]+[\-_])*[a-z\d]+\.)*([a-z\d]+[\-_])*[a-z\d]+$` found here https://nomicon.io/DataStructures/Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-release (`v0.6.0-0`) version of the [JS SDK](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-js/) comes with a built-in `accountId` validation function:

```
const ACCOUNT_ID_REGEX =
  /^(([a-z\d]+[-_])*[a-z\d]+\.)*([a-z\d]+[-_])*[a-z\d]+$/;

/**
 * Validates the Account ID according to the NEAR protocol
 * [Account ID rules](https://nomicon.io/DataStructures/Account#account-id-rules).
 *
 * @param accountId - The Account ID string you want to validate.
 */
export function validateAccountId(accountId: string): boolean {
  return (
    accountId.length >= 2 &&
    accountId.length <= 64 &&
    ACCOUNT_ID_REGEX.test(accountId)
  );
}
```

https://github.com/near/near-sdk-js/blob/dc6f07bd30064da96efb7f90a6ecd8c4d9cc9b06/lib/utils.js#L113

Feel free to implement this in your program too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do: `/^(\w|(?<!\.)\.)+(?<!\.)\.(testnet|near)$/gm`

**Breakdown**

```
^                 # start of line
(
  \w              # match alphanumeric characters
  |               # OR
  (?<!\.)\.       # dots can't be preceded by dots
)+
(?<!\.)           # "." should not precede:
\.                # "."
(testnet|near)    # match "testnet" or "near"
$                 # end of line
```

Try the Regex out: https://regex101.com/r/vctRlo/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match word characters only, separated by a dot:

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.(?:testnet|near)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\.\w+)*` Optionally repeat `.` and 1+ word characters
- `\.` Match `.`
- `(?:testnet|near)` Match either `testnet` or `near`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vtFrAi/1)

A bit broader variant matching whitespace character excluding the dot:

```
^[^\s.]+(?:\.[^\s.]+)*\.(?:testnet|near)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BdzTNX/1)